# Modifying grid properties in MapInfo Pro 15.2

Tags: grid, mapinfo

How to modify grid line properties like making grid without tick marks using MapInfo Pro 15.2 software?

Comment: I'm new to MapInfo. I have created grid using grid option in MapInfo but i didn't find any options for changing its properties. I wanna prepare a map where the grid should be invisible and coordinate label should be visible. whereas, in ArcGIS we can modify in layer properties dialog.

Answer (score 0):

If you have points and polygons on the same file/layer then you should have two object properties you can just right click then get Layer Properties to modify those (see enclosed screen shots bellow)

[Pic MapInfo Layers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rlyLX.png)

just select the polygon/point the set to N on Filling and Border

[Pic Layer Options settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/22Efg.png)